# How to set connection to down by default with nmcli

Tags: networking, vpn, nmcli

`nmcli` allows to disable a connection using `nmcli connection down <id>`.
But let's say I have a connection that I want to disable by default,
and maybe only in rare cases activate it.

How can I configure that, so that I don't have to use `nmcli connection down` on every system-startup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to set the connection's `autoconnect` property to `no`:

```
nmcli connection modify <connection> connection.autoconnect no
```